# Как при наличии отладочных символов только своей dll получить её переменные из дампа памяти приложения?

Tags: visual-studio, dll, отладка, dump

Есть моя DLL библиотека (проект Visual Studio 2013). Ее используют чужие программы. Во время работы этих программ было сохранено несколько полных дампов память процессов этих программ.
Я открываю эти дампы в моем Visual Studio проекте. Отладочные символы я имею только для моей DLL. При этом, если во время сохранения дампа исполнялся код одной из функций моей DLL, то видно все символы в исходном коде, место текущего исполнения итд. Но если, исполнялся другой код, я никаких данных не вижу и посмотреть текущее значение переменных моей DLL не могу. Локальные переменные ясное дело недоступны, так как их нет, но и статические данные тоже не видны.

Как просматривать данные моей DLL?

Comment: Ого! Это целое искусство.

Comment: А у вас есть символы (то есть, pdb) на чужие DLL?

Comment: @VladD, судя по оригинальному заголовку, чужих pdb нет.

Comment: @Qwertiy: Ну тогда в силе первый комментарий :)

Comment: Pdb только моей DLL. VladD, а где можно найти информацию о том, почему это так? Я не понимаю до конца, почему в 1-м случае данные видны, а в другом нет.

Comment: Вам понадобится программа **DebugView** + API функция **OutputDebugString**.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Не уверен, можно ли это сделать через студию. Но точно можно через WinDBG:

1. Открыть дамп.
2. Включить ссылки в выводе:

   ```
   .prefer_dml 1
   ```
3. Прописать путь к символам:

   ```
   .sympath+ srv*
   ```
4. Загрузить SOS (пусть исправить на соответствующий версии и платформе)

   для 4.0:

   ```
   .loadby sos clr
   ```

   для <4.0

   ```
   .loadby sos mscorwks
   ```

   или по полному пути

   ```
   .load C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\SOS.dll
   ```
5. Найти EEClass для того типа, для которого хочется посмотреть статические поля

   ```
   > !name2ee mscorlib.dll System.Console
   Module: 0000064278854000 (mscorlib.dll)
   Token: 0x000000000200008b
   MethodTable: 00000642788c8d10
   EEClass: 0000064278a271a8
   Name: System.Console
   ```
6. Посмотреть статические поля:

   ```
   > !dumpclass 0000064278a271a8
   Class Name: System.Console
   mdToken: 000000000200008b (C:\WINDOWS\assembly\GAC_64\mscorlib\2.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089\mscorlib.dll)
   Parent Class: 00000642788c0c30
   Module: 0000064278854000
   Method Table: 00000642788c8d10
   Vtable Slots: 4
   Total Method Slots: 78
   Class Attributes: 100181  Abstract, 
   NumInstanceFields: 0
   NumStaticFields: d
   MT    Field   Offset                 Type VT     Attr            Value Name
   00000642788f5aa0  40002ae       d8 System.IO.TextReader  0   shared           static _in
   ```

Дальше перемещаться кликами по адресам объектов - в режиме DML по клику будет выполнятся соответствующая команда для дампа объекта.

По настройке WinDBG есть отличный мануал [Debugging Managed Code Using the Windows Debugger](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/ff540665(v=vs.85).aspx).

Comment: У меня неуправляемый код.

Comment: @Reffum тогда вам скорее всего неповезло :( может быть кто-то, хорошо разбирающийся в unmanaged-отладке поможет, но я бы поставил на вариант "не получится"